# mongoDB Quisiera convertir de "string" a "int" mis datos de año

Tags: mongodb

En mongodb quiero realizar un cambio de string a int Lo he planteado utilizando $convert pero me genera un tipo de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`

```
var fase4 = {"Date Of Death Year":{}}
var fase5 = {$convert:
                {$out: 
                    {input:"$Date Of Death Year", to: "int"}}
            }
   
db.RPM.updateMany(fase4,fase5)
```

`

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de que es lo que almacenas actualmente en uno de tus documentos... y puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener luego del update con ese documento?

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir un campo de tipo string a entero, utiliza [`$toInt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) pasando como segundo argumento de **updateMany** una pipeline:

```
db.RPM.updateMany({}, [{
    $set: {
        "Date Of Death Year": {
            $toInt: "$Date Of Death Year"
        }
    }
}])
```

Alternativamente puedes lograr lo mismo con [$convert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#-convert--aggregation-):

```
db.RPM.updateMany({}, [{
    $set: {
        "Date Of Death Year": {
           "$convert": {
                "input": "$Date Of Death Year",
                "to": "int"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Tu código actualmente falla porque `fase5` no es un array y no estás usando los parámetros de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

El operador $convert se usa para convertir un valor a un tipo de datos especificado.
Sin embargo, la sintaxis en tu declaración de update es incorrecta. El método updateMany() toma dos argumentos: un filtro que especifica qué documentos actualizar y una expresión de update que especifica el update que se aplicará a los documentos coincidentes.

La expresión de update debe usar el operador $set para especificar el nuevo valor del campo. Podes usar el operador $convert dentro del operador $set para convertir el valor del campo 'Date Of Death Year' en un número entero.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var fase4 = {"Date Of Death Year":{}};
var fase5 = {$set: {
    "Date Of Death Year": {
        $convert: {
            input: "$Date Of Death Year",
            to: "int"
        }
    }
}};
db.RPM.updateMany(fase4, fase5);
```

El update encontrará todos los documentos en la colección de RPM donde está presente el campo 'Date Of Death Year' y establecerá el valor del campo en un número entero mediante el operador $convert.

Comment: Buenas noches Nicolás,
de antemano gracias por responderme,  he probado lo que me has dicho pero no se me ha realizado un cambio de "string" a "Numero":
{
 "acknowledged" : true,
 "matchedCount" : 0,
 "modifiedCount" : 0
}
También lo aplique para otras columnas en las cuales quiero realizar lo mismo pero obtuve el mismo resultado.

Muchas gracias